# Most efficient way of counting number of rows in each group of a table

Tags: matlab

I have a table which has groups of rows, given by unique combinations of a few columns. I wish to compute the number of rows in each group. What is the most efficient way to do this? I know I can use `grpstats` but it seems to be very inefficient when there are a large number of groups.

For example

```
rng(0,'twister');
N = 30; % control number of groups

c1 = randi([1 N],1000000,1);
c2 = randi([1 N],1000000,1);
c3 = randi([1 N],1000000,1);

T = array2table([c1 c2 c3]);

tic; gT = grpstats(T, {'Var1' 'Var2' 'Var3'}, 'numel'); toc;
```

Using `grpstats` seems to really blow out the time quadratically or worse. When `N = 3`, it takes 0.73 seconds on my machine. When `N = 10`, it takes 2.6 seconds. When `N = 30`, it takes 72 seconds.

Comment: as an aside, you can reduce processing time by about 30% if you do a `T = sortrows(T)` before using `grpstats`!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be about **80 times faster** for your example (table with 1000000 rows and 3 columns):

```
[gT, ~, v] = unique(T, 'rows');
gT.GroupCount = accumarray(v, 1);
```